# $ajax no es una funcion

Tags: javascript, web, java-ee

Estoy desarrollando una página con java, y en una parte estoy empezando a usar js, cuando intento eliminar un producto, este no me deja, y cuando reviso la terminal de la página, me señala un error en ajax, y me dice que $ajax no es una funcion.

```
$(document).ready(function (){
$("tr #btnDelete").click(function (){
    var idp = $(this).parent().find("#idp").val();
    eliminar(idp);
});
function eliminar(idp){
    var url = "Controlador?accion=Delete";
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: url,
        data: "idp="+idp,
        success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            alert("Registro Eliminado");
        }
    });
}
```

});

este es el código de JavaScript

```
<tbody>
   <c:forEach var="car" items="${carrito}">
      <tr>
        <td>${car.getItem()}</td>
        <td>${car.getNombres()}</td>
        <td>${car.getDescripcion()}
        <img src="ControladorImg?id=${car.getIdPlato()}" width="100" height="100">
        </td>
        <td>${car.getPrecioVenta()}</td>
        <td>${car.getCantidad()}</td>
        <td>${car.getSubtotal()}</td>
        <td>
          <input type="hidden" id="idp" value="S/.${car.getIdPlato()}">
          <a href="#" id="btnDelete">Eliminar</a>                                 
        </td>
       </tr>
      </c:forEach>     
     </tbody>
```

este es una parte del código que corresponde al HTML, en el HTML he colocado sus scripts, tanto del bootstrap como del jQuery, he visto, perdóneme si me equivoco, de que esto se debe en parte a JQuery, pero le he cambiado, le he agregado y le he quitado ese script pero me sigue saliendo ese error.

Comment: Saludos. No pones todo el cuerpo de tu HTML; te comento **$.ajax** no es nativo del navegador; debes cargar (el que conozco) que ya tiene esa implementación el **jQuery** https://jquery.com/

Comment: Hola. Verifica qué librería jQuery estás cargando y dónde la estás cargando. Por lo general se suele cargar en el `head` del HTML. Cuando sale *is not a function* suele ser porque no se está cargando la librería correctamente.

Comment: Coloca la lista de librerías que estas usando (en exactamente el mismo orden), además indica la versión de Jquery

Comment: hola que tal, he estado utilizando otras versiones de JQuery, y ya no me aparece el error de ajax, sin embargo, me aparece un error "post 500 (Internal Server Error)"